# how to successfully fix uploaded csv file error in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Please I am trying to import a data in a csv file to my database. the system successfully uploads some of the data and throw unknown error during the upload process. Someone should kindly assist me.

*** Controller.php***

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'file' => 'required',
]);

$upload = $request->file('file');
$filePath = $upload->getRealPath();

$file = fopen($filePath, 'r');

$header = fgetcsv($file);
$escapedHeader = [];

// data validation
foreach ($header as $key => $value) {
    $escapedItem = strtolower($value);
    array_push($escapedHeader, $escapedItem);

}

//looping through colums to get data
while ($columns = fgetcsv($file)) {
    if ($columns[0] == "") {
        continue;
    }

    //trim data
    foreach ($columns as $key => &$value) {
        $value = ucwords($value);
    }

    $data = array_combine($escapedHeader, $columns);

    $name = $data['name'];
    $contact = $data['contact'];
    $email = $data['email'];
    $role = $data['role'];
    $interview_date = $data['interview_date'];

    $appdata = new Applicant;
    $appdata->name = $name;
    $appdata->contact = $contact;
    $appdata->email = $email;
    $appdata->role = $role;
    $appdata->interview_date = $interview_date;

    $appdata->save();
}

return back()->with('status', 'Applicant Data Loaded Successfully');
```

***Below is the error showing*** after importing some of the data from the csv file.
[image]